# Django request object security

Tags: django

I'm building a Django application that will be on the public internet and i'm wondering how to hide the user object(that is part of request object) being hacked.

Is there a way for me to not pass the user object to the template?

Comment: no one, i mean NO ONE can be able to reach your request object from the browser on normal conditions.

Comment: Why do you think passing it to the template is a security risk? Who has access to the templates?